# Garbled high bits on serial output

Tags: serial, arduino-due

I'm trying to send the byte `0x5A` (`0b01011010`) on the serial output of an Arduino Due. My program is based on [this example project](https://github.com/klangner/arduino-due-rust), but I've stripped out all the unrelated parts:

```
#![feature(lang_items)]
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

extern crate sam3x;

pub mod rust_base;
use sam3x::*;
use sam3x::hal::peripherals::{Peripheral};
use sam3x::drivers::led::{Led};
use sam3x::hal::rtt::{init_timer, wait_ms};
use sam3x::hal::pmc;
use sam3x::hal::uart;


#[link_section=".vectors"]
pub static VECTOR_TABLE: VectorTable =
    VectorTable {
        reset_handler : start,
        exceptions    : [0; 14],
    };


fn start() -> ! {
    init_timer();
    pmc::enable_peripheral_clock_0(Peripheral::PioC);

    let led = Led::connect(Peripheral::PioB, 27).expect("Wrong pin for led.");
    let tx = uart::Tx::init(uart::BR_9600);

    let mut led_on = true;
    led.on();
    loop {
        tx.write_byte(0b01011010);

        wait_ms(250);
        if led_on {
            led.off()
        } else {
            led.on()
        }
        led_on = !led_on;
    }
}
```

As you can see, all I do is send out the byte `0x5A` four times a second, with some LED blinking just to show the program is running.

My problem is that if I connect a serial terminal program with 9600-8N1 settings, I am not getting `0x5A`; instead, I am getting mostly `0xBA`, and sometimes a `0x9A` slips through.

Writing out the bits:

```
0101 1010    5A
1011 1010    BA
1001 1010    9A
```

Note that the lower nybble is always correct, which is why I don't think it's a serial communication setting issue; also, it's pretty clear from [`uart::Tx::init`'s implementation](https://github.com/klangner/sam3x/blob/a34e0e2241951f49e1a990e05fe45175fafb95c5/src/hal/uart.rs#L84) that it defaults to no parity bits.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this error is specific to the Rust ARM library I am using; quoting from https://github.com/klangner/sam3x/issues/9:

> It looks that at bound rate=9600 the timer sends data with the speed of ~888. And then computer can't understand the output.

Based on this, I started playing around with the baud rate I pass to the library when initializing it, and using 11000 instead of 9600 empirically seems to work (i.e. I am seeing a steady stream of `0x5A` on my PC receiving at 9600).